# Laravel Field Validation: Either 8 or 16 Digits is Allowed

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-validation

I'm trying to validate a text field using Laravel's validation class. The same text field can either have exactly 8 digits or 16 digits. The below code did not work.

```
    $validationRules = [
        'number' => 'required|digits:8/16',
    ];
```

Comment: Maybe you could use a regex `(\d{8}|\d{16})` https://www.debuggex.com/r/T70gdEzmCV3LuT31

Comment: or conditional rules https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#conditionally-adding-rules or custom rules https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-validation-rules, while the regex approach seems most elegant

Comment: Instead of using regex you should create custom validation rule to handle this case. It's true that regex will work faster rather than calling custom method, but it's not that easy to read (especially for longer patterns)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
 $validationRules = [
    'number' => 'required|regex:/^(\d{8}|\d{16})$/',
 ];
```